# cflogin in cfscript

Tags: coldfusion, cflogin

I'm trying to learn the new cfscript syntax, as well as use cflogin.
I'm guessing I can't mix cf tags in cfscript, and I don't see a script equivalent to cflogin, cflogout, cfloginuser.

Should I call a component that is written in the CF8 syntax in order to use cflogin?

```
public void function onRequest(required string Page) output="true" {
if (StructKeyExists(url,"logout")) {
 <cflogout>
}
<cflogin>
 local.qryUsr = new Components.Usr.Login(form);
 if (local.qryUsr.Recordcount) {
  <cfloginuser name="#form.UsrName#" password="#form.UsrPassword#" roles="#local.qryUsr.Roles#">
 } else {
  request.errorMessage = "Incorrect login";
  include login/login.cfm;
  return;
 }
</cflogin>
include arguments.Page;
}
```

Comment: I think this question needs to be revisited in the context of cf9 syntax.  Is there a way to do this in script now that we're supposed to be able to write components from top to bottom using the script syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot directly mix tags and scripts.  However, you can fake it by writing function wrappers around the tags:

```
<cffunction name="logout">
   <cflogout />
</cffunction>
```

and call like:

```
logout();
```

Obviously, this is a trivial example.  You'd want to specify your arguments, your return value, etc. in your actual code.

Note one:  Do not do this for a generic query function that accepts user input, as you won't be able to use cfqueryparam.

Note two:  I generally don't do this.  If I'm writing code that depends on tag-only operations, I use the tag syntax.

Comment: Oh, ok.  Thanks!
I guess I'll forgo using cflogin (still) and simply use a session variable to see if they're logged in.

Comment: You can rewrite these and put them in a library, or use the library(ies) from cflib.org, and simply include them.  Then, you can call them wherever.  That would let you use cflogin if that is your specific goal.

Answer (score 0):

as a side note, there is a small effort going on over at [CFLib.org](http://cflib.org) to create functions for all CF Tags.
check out [CFMLLib](http://cflib.org/library/CFMLLib) for more details

Comment: cflib.org is interesting.
Any time I can view source code, I appreciate it!
I suppose a <cflogin> would have to be written as a custom tag.

Comment: Phillip -- these are rewritten as functions, which are not the same as custom tags.

Comment: Right.  I guess I thought 'custom tag' because cflogin has an opening and closing tag.