# Is there a script equivalent of cflogin?

Tags: coldfusion, cflogin

Pretty much all of the ColdFusion language has been made available in some form using the cfscript syntax in ColdFusion 9.  One item that I have not be able to find, though, is whether or not there is a script equivalent to the cflogin tag.

If there isn't, is there maybe a workaround using flash remoting gateway?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712223/cflogin-in-cfscript

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate.  The question you referenced has to do with CF8.  CF9 had a complete overhaul of the scripting language.  Some people have claimed that everything that could be done with tags could now, in cf9, also be done with script.  It appears that this may not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<cflogin>` in script style is not supported, but you can write your own.

For all supported tags in CF9 script, see: [Extending ColdFusion Pages with CFML Scripting - 
What is supported in CFScript](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSe9cbe5cf462523a02805926a1237efcbfd5-7ffe.html)

Answer (score 0):

why not roll your own. Write a function using the cf tag version, that uses cflogin then call that from cfscript as in

logUserIn(username, pass);

the method works for any cf tag that does not have its equivalent in cfscript.

hth,
larry

Comment: That can't work in this case.  cflogin creates a special transient scope that is available during the execution of the cflogin tag.  It doesn't exist outside of that, not even in the request scope.